# To prove: If a graph is k-colorable, then it must have a k-complete graph as it's subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

The above is kind of my conjecture. Please help me prove it.

Comment: Say please, what is your trying?

Comment: I found the answer. This conjecture is wrong. Grözsch graph.